# use perl to get information using regexs

Tags: regex, perl

All,

I have the following output from a command that I run in Perl. However, I am only interested in capturing the components and their respective statuses. (I.e. the "component" and "status" columns)

I've been thinking about how to approach this using regular expressions. I would like to assume that i will not really know the names of the components as in the future there may be additional components in the column. I don't care about the two middle columns (process-type or pid).

Any suggestions would be helpful.

my $consoleStatus = `opmnctl status 2>&1`;

```
-------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
component          | process-type       |     pid | status
-------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
serverpro          | logloaderd         |     N/A | Down
www-daemon         | www-daemon         |   10000 | Alive
OXQA               | oqa                |   99894 | Alive
SDFW               | OC4X_SECURITY      |   27683 | Alive
FTP_Servers        | HTTP_Server        |   21252 | Alive
OID                | OID                |   27207 | Alive
DSA                | DSA                |     N/A | Down
```

Regards,

Comment: I would suggest that splitting each column and then extract 1st and last column if each column is separated using pipe(|).  Any specific reason why u need to approach using reg exp?

Comment: Once you've got the information into Perl what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [`opmnctl` options](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Opmnctl) to simplify what the Perl has to process, maybe:

```
opmnctl status -noheaders -fsep '|' -fmt %cmp%sta
```

I'd suggest using [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), and split on the pipe `|` characters that delimit the fields.

Here's a short snippet that may give you some ideas.  If you can use some `opmnctl` options, you'd be able to simplify this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %component_status;

LINE: for ( split( /\n/, $consoleStatus ) ) {
    # Skip the furniture in the opmnctl output
    next LINE if m/^component\W/ || m/^-/;

    # field 0 is the component, field 3 the status.
    my ( $component, $status ) = (split( / +\| */, $_ ))[0,3];

    $component_status{$component} = $status;
}

warn Dumper( \%component_status );
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'DSA' => 'Down',
      'FTP_Servers' => 'Alive',
      'SDFW' => 'Alive',
      'serverpro' => 'Down',
      'OID' => 'Alive',
      'OXQA' => 'Alive',
      'www-daemon' => 'Alive'
    };
```

Comment: It appears that there may be components with the same name and this being the case, I know hash keys need to be unique. Is there a "work-around" to this? Renaming the key before it's inserted could be an idea?

Comment: @sandster - Perhaps you might use the pid to differentiate between instances of the same component?  If so, you could compose your hash key from the component name and the pid, maybe `$component . ':' . $pid` or similar.  Obviously, you'd need to extract the pid from the opmnctl status output to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the layout of your output doesn't change, the component name doesn't have spaces, and the possible status are only 'Alive' and 'Down', you could use the given regex to match each line:

```
/^(\S+)\s+\|.+\|\s+(Alive|Down)$/
```

Below, I wrote a code that gets the input from STDIN, and prints out the component and it's status:

```
while(<STDIN>) {
    if( $_ =~ /^(\S+)\s+\|.+\|\s+(Alive|Down)$/ ) {
        print "$1 -> $2\n";
    }
}
```